# How to insert \0 into phpmyadmin without escaping?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I need to insert the following query, but using Excel csv:

```
INSERT INTO tablename ('column1') VALUES ('\0*_sometext');
```

However, when I simply import it via excel, I actually insert:

```
INSERT INTO tablename ('column1') VALUES ('\\0*_sometest');
```

Is there a way around it?

I'm also considering writing a php script to use the insert query.

Comment: Uuhm, in most programming languages `\0` equals `null`, `nil`, or w/e. I am confused by you trying to insert `null` + `'sometext'`, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I am also confused why it's like that, but this is the query that a plugin uses from the database, so I want to import a dataset matching the syntax

Comment: '\0' is normally taken to mean the ASCII NUL *character*; this is different than nil/null although some languages (notably C, have a direct conversion between null and 0).

Comment: Is it possible to import the NUL character somehow via excel?

Comment: @GRS I'm not sure about that - if the input stream itself contains NUL (the single character with the value 0, not the two characters representing the escape for NUL),  that *may* work. YMMV, especially since NUL has historical significance in string processing.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tablename ('column1') VALUES (CONCAT(CHAR(0), '*_sometext'));`

Comment: And yes, it's possible to have the same sequence of characters in an Excel spreadsheet

Comment: @MarkBaker How to get that (an expression yielding the equivalent `'\0*_sometext'` value) from the Excel import though?

Comment: In Excel, `=CHAR(0) & "*_sometext"`

Comment: When I write =CHAR(0) in excel, I get #VALUE! in the cell content, and after importing the row into phpmyadmin, I also import #VALUE and not \0.

Comment: If I import \0, I actually import \\0. It seems to be impossible to do it via csv/excel and I'm going to have to write a lot of php queries